# Will my LG G6 be able to clearly capture the solar eclipse corona in a 360 photo?

Tags: sun, eclipse

Will my LG G6 be able to clearly capture the corona in a 360 photo, when the sun is fully eclipsed?  I plan on using the 360 mode that comes with the default camera app.

Comment: highly unlikely, its going to be absolutely tiny

Answer (score 1):

The sun's core appears to be the same diameter as the moon as viewed from the surface of the Earth - about 1/2° of arc. Use you planned setup to take an image with the moon in it and see for yourself. Although it varies with solar activity as well as with exposure settings used, the corona will rarely be more than about 3 diameters of the sun/moon as captured by cameras also trying to capture the areas surrounding the camera and exposing for the surrounding area to be visible but fairly dark.